In football, advantage applied in 2nd yellow card situation, later followed by red card
During a recent grassroots football game a player already on a yellow card commits another bookable offence, the referee played advantage.
When the ball went out of play, the referee went and gave the offending player a 2nd yellow card followed by a red card.
Was the referee correct?

We don't know what kind of offense happened there, but according to the LotG this was likely a correct call.
Law 12:

Advantage
If the referee plays the advantage for an offence for which
a caution/sending-off would have been issued had play been stopped,
this caution/sending-off must be issued when the ball is next out of
play. However, if the offence was denying the opposing team an obvious
goal-scoring opportunity the player is cautioned for unsporting
behaviour; if the offence was interfering with or stopping a promising
attack, the player is not cautioned.
Advantage should not be applied in situations involving serious foul
play, violent conduct or a second cautionable offence unless there is
a clear opportunity to score a goal. The referee must send off the
player when the ball is next out of play, but if the player plays the
ball or challenges/interferes with an opponent, the referee will stop
play, send off the player and restart with an indirect free kick,
unless the player committed a more serious offence.

